# How to inspect touch hold in Android

Tags: android

how can I inspect(to do some stuff) while user is holding touch screen(it doesn't mater how much points) and stop doing this stuff after releasing . 
I would be very grateful for help
 **EDIT**
I have tried to do the same but it doesn't recognize ACTION_UP event.

Answer (score 0):

You override onTouchEvent of the view.  You start doing stuff when you see an ACTION_DOWN and stop when you see ACTION_UP

Comment: I have tried to do the same but it doesn't recognize ACTION_UP event.

Comment: Are you possibly getting an ACTION_CANCEL in there somewhere?  In that case you won't see an ACTION_UP.  But this method does work, I use it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e("", "Longpress detected");
    }
});

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
};
```